# Десериализации json-строк ко всему датасету

Tags: python-3.x, json, pandas

**В датасете есть вектор '*user_json*', в котором содержится некие сериализованные json-строки.**

```
data_dir = 'data'
filename = 'gender_age_dataset.txt'
file_path = '/'.join([data_dir,filename])
df = pd.read_csv(file_path, sep='\t')
```

**Что содержит в себе одна строка  'user_json'- атрибуты 'url' и 'timestamp'**

```
print(json.loads(df.iloc[0].user_json)):
{'visits': [{'url': 'http://zebra-zoya.ru/200028-chehol-organayzer-dlja-macbook-11-grid-it.html?utm_campaign=397720794&utm_content=397729344&utm_medium=cpc&utm_source=begun', 'timestamp': 1419688144068}, {'url': 'http://news.yandex.ru/yandsearch?cl4url=chezasite.com/htc/htc-one-m9-delay-86327.html&lr=213&rpt=story', 'timestamp': 1426666298001}, {'url': 'http://www.sotovik.ru/news/240283-htc-one-m9-zaderzhivaetsja.html', 'timestamp': 1426666298000}, {'url': 'http://news.yandex.ru/yandsearch?cl4url=chezasite.com/htc/htc-one-m9-delay-86327.html&lr=213&rpt=story', 'timestamp': 1426661722001}, {'url': 'http://www.sotovik.ru/news/240283-htc-one-m9-zaderzhivaetsja.html', 'timestamp': 1426661722000}]}
```

**пример 2 строк с заголовком:**

```
gender  age     uid     user_json
F       18-24   d50192e5-c44e-4ae8-ae7a-7cfe67c8b777    {"visits": [{"url": "http://zebra-zoya.ru/200028-chehol-organayzer-dlja-macbook-11-grid-it.html?utm_campaign=397720794&utm_content=397729344&utm_medium=cpc&utm_source=begun", "timestamp": 1419688144068}, {"url": "http://news.yandex.ru/yandsearch?cl4url=chezasite.com/htc/htc-one-m9-delay-86327.html&lr=213&rpt=story", "timestamp": 1426666298001}, {"url": "http://www.sotovik.ru/news/240283-htc-one-m9-zaderzhivaetsja.html", "timestamp": 1426666298000}, {"url": "http://news.yandex.ru/yandsearch?cl4url=chezasite.com/htc/htc-one-m9-delay-86327.html&lr=213&rpt=story", "timestamp": 1426661722001}, {"url": "http://www.sotovik.ru/news/240283-htc-one-m9-zaderzhivaetsja.html", "timestamp": 1426661722000}]}
M       25-34   d502331d-621e-4721-ada2-5d30b2c3801f    {"visits": [{"url": "http://sweetrading.ru/?p=900", "timestamp": 1419717886224}, {"url": "http://sweetrading.ru/?p=884", "timestamp": 1419717884437}, {"url": "http://sweetrading.ru/?p=1002", "timestamp": 1419717816375}, {"url": "http://101.ru/?an=port_channel_mp3", "timestamp": 1419717804934}, {"url": "http://sweetrading.ru/?cat=62", "timestamp": 1419714194423}, {"url": "http://sweetrading.ru/?p=1046", "timestamp": 1419713998481}, {"url": "http://sweetrading.ru/?p=978", "timestamp": 1419713927085}, {"url": "http://sweetrading.ru/?cat=171", "timestamp": 1419713908863}, {"url": "http://sweetrading.ru/?cat=62", "timestamp": 1419713908679}, {"url": "http://sweetrading.ru/?p=3648", "timestamp": 1419713798879}, {"url": "http://oesex.ru/955457", "timestamp": 1419595564407}, {"url": "http://www.interfax.ru/russia/408800", "timestamp": 1419542965224}, {"url": "http://101.ru/?an=port_channel_mp3&channel=30", "timestamp": 1418818241900}, {"url": "http://www.interfax.ru/russia/413508", "timestamp": 1418802080857}, {"url": "http://www.euroavtoprokat.ru/sitemap/car-rental/france.htm", "timestamp": 1418722961181}, {"url": "http://www.euroavtoprokat.ru/sitemap/car-rental.htm", "timestamp": 1418722945825}, {"url": "http://www.euroavtoprokat.ru/car-rental/germany.htm", "timestamp": 1418722937847}, {"url": "http://www.euroavtoprokat.ru/car-rental/germany.htm", "timestamp": 1418722923196}, {"url": "http://www.euroavtoprokat.ru/sitemap/car-rental.htm", "timestamp": 1418722909804}, {"url": "http://www.eavtoprokat.ru/prokat-avto/france", "timestamp": 1418646101953}, {"url": "http://www.wordparts.ru/numeral/", "timestamp": 1418592793587}, {"url": "http://rsdn.ru/forum/alg/3305190.flat", "timestamp": 1418591162814}, {"url": "http://www.euroavtoprokat.ru/car-rental/turkey/istanbul.htm", "timestamp": 1418571531780}, {"url": "http://citieslist.ru/", "timestamp": 1418488992092}, {"url": "http://www.euroavtoprokat.ru/car-rental/turkey/istanbul.htm", "timestamp": 1418480798674}, {"url": "http://rutv.ru/brand/show/episode/453757", "timestamp": 1418253037406}, {"url": "http://www.fodors.com/community/europe/best-car-rental-company-in-italy.cfm", "timestamp": 1418247198586}, {"url": "http://wheelsabroad.com/car-rental/united-kingdom/england/london?gclid=cjwkeaia-5-kbrdylpg5096r8masjabqedm4cmiichc-_-ewkbtsqyci5bu9ucwvjmxp4o0tficaarocljdw_wcb", "timestamp": 1418245144696}, {"url": "http://lestinet.com/site/stopagent.ru", "timestamp": 1418243376170}, {"url": "http://android-help.ru/q2a/16774/\u043a\u0430\u043a-\u043f\u043e\u043b\u0443\u0447\u0438\u0442\u044c-root-\u043f\u0440\u0430\u0432\u0430-\u043d\u0430-philips-w832-android-4-0-4", "timestamp": 1418169606439}, {"url": "http://club.dns-shop.ru/rabinovich/blog/\u044f-\u0432\u0441\u0435-\u0435\u0449\u0435-\u0434\u0435\u0440\u0436\u0443\u0441\u044c-\u043e\u0431\u0437\u043e\u0440-\u0441\u043c\u0430\u0440\u0442\u0444\u043e\u043d\u0430-philips-xenium-w832/", "timestamp": 1418169602505}, {"url": "http://www.supportforum.philips.com/ru/showthread.php?1529-philips-xenium-w832/page6", "timestamp": 1418167859617}, {"url": "http://www.supportforum.philips.com/ru/showthread.php?842-\u043d\u0435-\u0440\u0430\u0431\u043e\u0442\u0430\u0435\u0442-gps-\u0432-\u0441\u043c\u0430\u0440\u0442\u0444\u043e\u043d\u0435-philips-xenium-w832", "timestamp": 1418166430112}, {"url": "http://rabota.ua/info/jobsearcher/post/umora.aspx", "timestamp": 1418114698621}, {"url": "http://www.enter.ru/product/appliances/myasorubka-philips-hr2728-2020103007131", "timestamp": 1418053557067}, {"url": "http://www.ferra.ru/ru/byt/news/2013/12/02/polaris-pmg-1805/", "timestamp": 1417866883735}, {"url": "http://www.ferra.ru/ru/byt/news/2013/10/12/bosch-mfw6-propower/", "timestamp": 1417862586856}, {"url": "http://www.linotype.com/1266/neuehelvetica-family.html", "timestamp": 1417856979616}, {"url": "http://www.linotype.com/1546/tradegothic-family.html?site=webfonts", "timestamp": 1417812010753}, {"url": "http://www.vandelaydesign.com/best-ecommerce-website-designs/", "timestamp": 1417807232287}, {"url": "http://www.awwwards.com/20-of-the-very-best-e-commerce-web-sites.html", "timestamp": 1417805189928}, {"url": "http://101.ru/?an=port_channel_mp3&channel=82", "timestamp": 1417711286305}, {"url": "http://www.just.ru/myasorubki/56658_elektromyasorybky_kenwood_mg_450/?from=yandex_msk&utm_source=yandex&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=10817239_model_bytovaya-tehnika-melkaya_msk_p_api&utm_content=612422293_2792852770_\u043c\u044f\u0441\u043e\u0440\u0443\u0431\u043a\u0443 mg 450&position_type=premi", "timestamp": 1417701042306}, {"url": "http://101.ru/?an=port_channel_mp3&channel=5", "timestamp": 1417695760398}, {"url": "http://101.ru/?an=port_channel_mp3&channel=5", "timestamp": 1417689964129}, {"url": "http://101.ru/?an=port_channel_mp3&channel=17", "timestamp": 1417683034834}, {"url": "http://www.kenwoodworld.com/ru-ru/all-products/blenders-mixers-and-meat-grinders/meat-grinders-ru/-mg350-0w21910001", "timestamp": 1417608945879}, {"url": "http://101.ru/?an=port_channel_mp3&channel=24", "timestamp": 1417605700777}, {"url": "http://101.ru/?an=port_channel_mp3&channel=24", "timestamp": 1417605639264}, {"url": "http://101.ru/?an=port_channel_mp3&channel=82", "timestamp": 1417605624817}, {"url": "http://www.kenwoodworld.com/ru-ru/all-products/blenders-mixers-and-meat-grinders/meat-grinders-ru/mg470-meat-grinder-0wmg470008", "timestamp": 1417604804579}, {"url": "http://livedemo00.template-help.com/magento_48517/blackberry-bold-9000-phone.html", "timestamp": 1417604730951}, {"url": "http://www.kenwoodworld.com/ru-ru/all-products/blenders-mixers-and-meat-grinders/meat-grinders-ru/mg470-meat-grinder-0wmg470008", "timestamp": 1417548651645}, {"url": "http://www.kenwoodworld.com/en-int/products/blenders/meat-grinders/mg474-meat-grinder", "timestamp": 1417548321763}, {"url": "http://www.kenwoodworld.com/ru-ru/all-products/blenders-mixers-and-meat-grinders/meat-grinders-ru/-mg350-0w21910001", "timestamp": 1417548310507}, {"url": "http://www.kenwoodworld.com/ru-ru/all-products/blenders-mixers-and-meat-grinders/meat-grinders-ru/-mg350-0w21910001", "timestamp": 1417548309162}, {"url": "http://www.kenwoodworld.com/ru-ru/all-products/blenders-mixers-and-meat-grinders/meat-grinders-ru/-mg350-0w21910001?feat=6405fda1-43cc-42cc-8860-1c2a492555c5&tabsegment=key-features", "timestamp": 1417548297576}, {"url": "http://www.kenwoodworld.com/ru-ru/all-products/blenders-mixers-and-meat-grinders/meat-grinders-ru/-mg350-0w21910001?tabsegment=key-features", "timestamp": 1417548284970}, {"url": "http://www.kenwoodworld.com/ru-ru/all-products/blenders-mixers-and-meat-grinders/meat-grinders-ru/-mg350-0w21910001", "timestamp": 1417548264964}, {"url": "http://www.kenwoodworld.com/en-int/products/blenders/meat-grinders", "timestamp": 1417546314287}, {"url": "http://www.kenwoodworld.com/ru-ru/all-products/blenders-mixers-and-meat-grinders/meat-grinders-ru/mg700-meat-grinder-0wmg700006", "timestamp": 1417545459520}, {"url": "http://www.kenwoodworld.com/ru-ru/all-products/blenders-mixers-and-meat-grinders/meat-grinders-ru/mg700-meat-grinder-0wmg700006", "timestamp": 1417545200191}, {"url": "http://www.kenwoodworld.com/ru-ru/all-products/kmix-by-kenwood/kmix-kitchen-machines-/kmx51-kmix-kitchen-machine-0wkmx51002", "timestamp": 1417545116313}, {"url": "http://www.kenwoodworld.com/ru-ru/all-products/blenders-mixers-and-meat-grinders/meat-grinders-ru/---mg517---0wmg517007", "timestamp": 1417544991760}, {"url": "http://www.kenwoodworld.com/ru-ru/all-products/blenders-mixers-and-meat-grinders/meat-grinders-ru/-mg350-0w21910001", "timestamp": 1417544967371}, {"url": "http://www.kenwoodworld.com/ru-ru/all-products/blenders-mixers-and-meat-grinders/meat-grinders-ru/-mg350-0w21910001?feat=ac86d868-3ea4-4523-93e1-885bbf4222cd&tabsegment=key-features", "timestamp": 1417544772661}, {"url": "http://www.kenwoodworld.com/ru-ru/all-products/blenders-mixers-and-meat-grinders/meat-grinders-ru/-mg350-0w21910001?feat=3a288c22-e5f2-448e-a573-ccde95fd2341&tabsegment=key-features", "timestamp": 1417544765049}, {"url": "http://www.kenwoodworld.com/ru-ru/all-products/blenders-mixers-and-meat-grinders/meat-grinders-ru/-mg350-0w21910001?feat=ac86d868-3ea4-4523-93e1-885bbf4222cd&tabsegment=key-features", "timestamp": 1417544748628}, {"url": "http://www.kenwoodworld.com/ru-ru/all-products/blenders-mixers-and-meat-grinders/meat-grinders-ru/-mg350-0w21910001?tabsegment=key-features", "timestamp": 1417544731238}, {"url": "http://www.kenwoodworld.com/ru-ru/all-products/blenders-mixers-and-meat-grinders/meat-grinders-ru/-mg350-0w21910001", "timestamp": 1417544522237}, {"url": "http://www.kenwoodworld.com/ru-ru/all-products/blenders-mixers-and-meat-grinders/meat-grinders-ru/-mg350-0w21910001", "timestamp": 1417544351791}, {"url": "http://www.kenwoodworld.com/ru-ru/all-products/blenders-mixers-and-meat-grinders/meat-grinders-ru/-mg350-0w21910001", "timestamp": 1417544282950}, {"url": "http://www.kenwoodworld.com/ru-ru", "timestamp": 1417544269909}, {"url": "http://www.kenwoodworld.com/ru-ru/all-products/blenders-mixers-and-meat-grinders/meat-grinders-ru/mg516-meat-grinder-and-roto-food-cutter-0wmg516006?tabsegment=specifications", "timestamp": 1417544204394}, {"url": "http://www.kenwoodworld.com/ru-ru/all-products/blenders-mixers-and-meat-grinders/meat-grinders-ru/mg516-meat-grinder-and-roto-food-cutter-0wmg516006", "timestamp": 1417544190747}, {"url": "http://www.kenwoodworld.com/ru-ru/all-products/blenders-mixers-and-meat-grinders/meat-grinders-ru/mg516-meat-grinder-and-roto-food-cutter-0wmg516006", "timestamp": 1417544045014}, {"url": "http://www.kenwoodworld.com/ru-ru/all-products/blenders-mixers-and-meat-grinders/meat-grinders-ru/mg516-meat-grinder-and-roto-food-cutter-0wmg516006?tabsegment=specifications", "timestamp": 1417544035023}, {"url": "http://www.kenwoodworld.com/ru-ru/all-products/blenders-mixers-and-meat-grinders/meat-grinders-ru/mg516-meat-grinder-and-roto-food-cutter-0wmg516006", "timestamp": 1417544015196}, {"url": "http://www.kenwoodworld.com/ru-ru", "timestamp": 1417544004579}, {"url": "http://www.kenwoodworld.com/ru-ru/all-products/blenders-mixers-and-meat-grinders/meat-grinders-ru/mg510-meat-grinder-0wmg510009?tabsegment=specifications", "timestamp": 1417543914820}, {"url": "http://www.kenwoodworld.com/uk/search-results", "timestamp": 1417543814629}, {"url": "http://www.kenwoodworld.com/uk/search-results", "timestamp": 1417543642699}, {"url": "http://www.kenwoodworld.com/uk/search-results", "timestamp": 1417543628088}, {"url": "http://www.kenwoodworld.com/uk/search-results", "timestamp": 1417543616074}, {"url": "http://www.kenwoodworld.com/uk/products/food-mixers/chef-major-attachments/potato-peeler-at444-awat444001", "timestamp": 1417543439173}, {"url": "http://www.kenwoodworld.com/uk/search-results", "timestamp": 1417543352117}, {"url": "http://www.kenwoodworld.com/uk/search-results", "timestamp": 1417543294005}, {"url": "http://www.kenwoodworld.com/uk/search-results", "timestamp": 1417543192107}, {"url": "http://www.kenwoodworld.com/uk", "timestamp": 1417543022466}, {"url": "http://www.kenwoodworld.com/ru-ru/all-products/blenders-mixers-and-meat-grinders/meat-grinders-ru/mg510-meat-grinder-0wmg510009?tabsegment=specifications", "timestamp": 1417542940415}, {"url": "http://www.kenwoodworld.com/ru-ru/all-products/blenders-mixers-and-meat-grinders/meat-grinders-ru/mg510-meat-grinder-0wmg510009?tabsegment=support", "timestamp": 1417542907491}, {"url": "http://www.kenwoodworld.com/ru-ru/all-products/blenders-mixers-and-meat-grinders/meat-grinders-ru/mg510-meat-grinder-0wmg510009?tabsegment=specifications", "timestamp": 1417542866623}, {"url": "http://www.kenwoodworld.com/ru-ru/all-products/blenders-mixers-and-meat-grinders/meat-grinders-ru/mg510-meat-grinder-0wmg510009", "timestamp": 1417542858206}, {"url": "http://www.kenwoodworld.com/ru-ru/all-products/blenders-mixers-and-meat-grinders/meat-grinders-ru/mg510-meat-grinder-0wmg510009", "timestamp": 1417542839578}, {"url": "http://www.kenwoodworld.com/ru-ru/all-products/blenders-mixers-and-meat-grinders/meat-grinders-ru/mg510-meat-grinder-0wmg510009", "timestamp": 1417542795850}, {"url": "http://www.kenwoodworld.com/ru-ru/all-products/blenders-mixers-and-meat-grinders/meat-grinders-ru/mg510-meat-grinder-0wmg510009", "timestamp": 1417542742883}, {"url": "http://www.kenwoodworld.com/ru-ru/all-products/blenders-mixers-and-meat-grinders/meat-grinders-ru/mg510-meat-grinder-0wmg510009", "timestamp": 1417542725367}, {"url": "http://www.kenwoodworld.com/ru-ru/all-products/blenders-mixers-and-meat-grinders/meat-grinders-ru/mg510-meat-grinder-0wmg510009", "timestamp": 1417542659966}, {"url": "http://www.kenwoodworld.com/ru-ru", "timestamp": 1417542501523}, {"url": "http://101.ru/?an=port_channel_mp3&channel=24", "timestamp": 1417542435930}, {"url": "http://www.shop-script.ru/platform/", "timestamp": 1417473193974}, {"url": "http://101.ru/?an=port_channel_mp3&channel=34", "timestamp": 1417451297674}]}
```

**Нужно 'url' и 'timestamp' стали векторами датасета df, как это реализовать ?**

Comment: @MaxU извините, сразу не подумал весь пример дать, так как он очень большой, а знания linux ограничены.. ну теперь знаю команду head

Comment: а как должен выглядеть результат?

Comment: @MaxU Датасет состоял из заголовков :  gender    age                                   uid  url timestamp

Comment: в `url` и `timestamp` - должны быть списки значений?

Comment: @MaxU как я понял из строения файла на каждую строку пола и возраста приходится 1 или несколько сайтов  который оно посетило и время... Далее этой пойдёт в модель обучения .. она же не сможет прочитать список значений для каждой строки .. ?

Comment: @MaxU мне кажется правильнее сделать дубляж строки на такое колличество раз, сколько посетили сайтов

Comment: а файл `gender_age_dataset.txt` вы сами создаете? по-моему лучше такие (вложенные) данные не сохранять в CSV

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76885/discussion-between---and-maxu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для парсинга сложных (вложенных) JSON (или словарей) можно воспользоваться [pd.io.json.json_normalize()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html), но для этого лучше сначала преобразовать данные в словарь:

```
In [161]: from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

In [162]: data = (df.drop('user_json', axis=1)
                    .join(df['user_json'].apply(lambda x: json.loads(x)))
                    .to_dict('records'))

In [163]: res = json_normalize(data, [['user_json','visits']], ['uid','gender','age'])

In [164]: res
Out[164]:
         timestamp                                                url                                   uid gender    age
0    1419688144068  http://zebra-zoya.ru/200028-chehol-organayzer-...  d50192e5-c44e-4ae8-ae7a-7cfe67c8b777      F  18-24
1    1426666298001  http://news.yandex.ru/yandsearch?cl4url=chezas...  d50192e5-c44e-4ae8-ae7a-7cfe67c8b777      F  18-24
2    1426666298000  http://www.sotovik.ru/news/240283-htc-one-m9-z...  d50192e5-c44e-4ae8-ae7a-7cfe67c8b777      F  18-24
3    1426661722001  http://news.yandex.ru/yandsearch?cl4url=chezas...  d50192e5-c44e-4ae8-ae7a-7cfe67c8b777      F  18-24
4    1426661722000  http://www.sotovik.ru/news/240283-htc-one-m9-z...  d50192e5-c44e-4ae8-ae7a-7cfe67c8b777      F  18-24
5    1419717886224                       http://sweetrading.ru/?p=900  d502331d-621e-4721-ada2-5d30b2c3801f      M  25-34
6    1419717884437                       http://sweetrading.ru/?p=884  d502331d-621e-4721-ada2-5d30b2c3801f      M  25-34
..             ...                                                ...                                   ...    ...    ...
100  1417542742883  http://www.kenwoodworld.com/ru-ru/all-products...  d502331d-621e-4721-ada2-5d30b2c3801f      M  25-34
101  1417542725367  http://www.kenwoodworld.com/ru-ru/all-products...  d502331d-621e-4721-ada2-5d30b2c3801f      M  25-34
102  1417542659966  http://www.kenwoodworld.com/ru-ru/all-products...  d502331d-621e-4721-ada2-5d30b2c3801f      M  25-34
103  1417542501523                  http://www.kenwoodworld.com/ru-ru  d502331d-621e-4721-ada2-5d30b2c3801f      M  25-34
104  1417542435930      http://101.ru/?an=port_channel_mp3&channel=24  d502331d-621e-4721-ada2-5d30b2c3801f      M  25-34
105  1417473193974                http://www.shop-script.ru/platform/  d502331d-621e-4721-ada2-5d30b2c3801f      M  25-34
106  1417451297674      http://101.ru/?an=port_channel_mp3&channel=34  d502331d-621e-4721-ada2-5d30b2c3801f      M  25-34

[107 rows x 5 columns]
```

Comment: отработало на отлично.

Comment: Ещё раз добрый вечер. Вопрос про этот же скрипт. На текущем примере 2 строк превратилось в 107, на полном файле их стало 5 мл.  Я запустил по этим 5 мл. записей скрипт по очистке домена и преформатирование времени, так скрипт уже висит 1 час) Можно ли в рамках этой темы задать вопрос об постобработке ?

Comment: @максимильин, лучше задать отдельный вопрос - это может пригодиться кому-то еще...